# Weird Javascript Timezones with Date()

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, unix-timestamp

Javascript hopeless here but I've got a problem I can't seem to understand, and don't know whether it's defined behavior in JS or not...

From what I can understand, `new Date()` returns the current time in the current timezone as reported by the browser. At the current time of writing this, I am in Milan, Italy (GMT +0200 CEST), so when performing the below:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

I get, as expected:

```
Sun Oct 07 2018 15:42:12 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
-120
```

However, again from what I understand, throwing milliseconds into the Date Constructor creates a date based off of Epoch Time, 1st January 1970 00:00:00 GMT +0000 - So why if I perform:

```
var date = new Date(0); // Note The 0
console.log(date);
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset())
```

Do I get:

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
-60
```

Did the browser for some reason change the timezone it thinks I am in? This is causing quite a few problems for me retrieving a unix timestamp from a database, and displaying it in the user's current timezone!

Any help or advice on this would be much appreciated!

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Well, on Jan 1st 1970 you would have been in CET, since it's in the middle of winter. But I wasn't aware that browsers would have this awareness of Daylight Saving.

Comment: @RobinZigmond generally it's the underlying OS that knows about daylight savings (or "summer") time.

Comment: of course, thanks @Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric timestamp value inside every Date instance, no matter how it is constructed, represents an offset from a fixed UTC "epoch" time.  When you construct a date in your locale, the timezone offset is taken into account when the Date instance timstamp is set. The timezone offset is *also* taken into account when you access parts of the date via locale-relative APIs like `.getTimezoneOffset()`.

Thus what matters is how you get date/time information *out* of the Date instance. If you use UTC APIs, you get UTC time information. If you use locale-relative APIs, you get  locale-relative values.

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log("locale-relative: " + d);
console.log("UTC: " + d.toUTCString());
```

Now, as to how you handle the system timestamp values you've got in your database, that depends on how your application works and what the dates mean in that context. If it's important that users see the dates in terms of what your server(s) will do with them, format the dates on the server with locale-relative APIs.  That would make sense if your application does some work based on local time. For example some banking applications (in the US) do things at night, but "night" in terms of late evening hours in the continental US.

If, on the other hand, the dates you store should be shown to your users in terms of *their* locales, then send the client the timestamp and format your dates as strings at the client with locale-relative APIs. That would be appropriate for an application that allows users to set up alarms etc: generally it makes sense for the user to think in terms of their own local time.

Comment: Right! So in my instance, I'm retrieving the timestamp, say `1514764800` which is `Monday, January 1, 2018 12:00:00 AM GMT +0000` - After a `console.log(1514764800 * 1000)` I get, `Mon Jan 01 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)` which is not the TZ the date was specified in, nor the user's locale?

Comment: Why do you think that is not in the user's locale? Note that generally January is not a daylight savings month, so the offset is 0100 and not 0200 for that date.

Comment: @FrankieDee the locale-relative APIs take the universal time value and show you what that would look like in the appropriate locale. Just because right now DST is in effect does not mean that it always is in effect. A date/time value from a non-DST month is shown with the non-DST offset.

Comment: Ahh okay - I wasn't aware that was happening, that makes more sense now.. I was taking a GMT +0000 date and expecting it to show it to me according to the timezone I am in currently, ie, with a DST effect if any.. Of course, it does make sense to display it according to whether at the time of the date, the DST effect was active or not... Thankyou for clearing that up!

Comment: @FrankieDee—historical support for DST and other timezone changes is only recent and not mandatory. Previously, Date methods just extrapolated current settings as if they applied always.

Comment: @RobG thank you for that information, I didn’t know that!! does browser support vary in regards to underlying DST information? Or is it pretty consistent now across browsers? :)

Comment: @FrankieDee browsers rely on the underlying operating system. You cannot absolutely rely on a client system to "correctly" show a date/time value, but that's not really your problem. Typical computer and mobile device operating systems all correctly handle time zone and DST information.